# Every bounded sequence in $R^n$ has atleast one limit point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came around this statement while reading a book on optimization. I don't understand however, how this statement is true?

$a_n = \{1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,...\}$ is a bounded sequence in $\Re$ but it does not converge to a single limit point, or I am misunderstanding something? It is even harder for me to imagine for a bounded set in $\Re^n$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to confuse "having a limit" and "having a limit point." The latter means there is a *subsequence* that has as a limit, and the limit is this point.

For your sequence the subsequence with even  indices clearly has a limit $-1$ and thus $-1$ is a limit point. Likewise, $1$ is a limit point considering the subqequence of odd indices.

Note that in the statement you quote it says "at least one" clearly hinting at the fact that there is some choice involved.

Comment: But isn't a limit point (say, p) of a set (say, E) by definition a point such that each of its neighborhoods contains at least one point in common with E _other than itself (i.e. other than p)_ (I'm following Rudin here)? In this case the only point in common with the sequence which every neighborhood of 1 (or -1) contains is itself, i.e. 1 (or -1). Hence I'm confused as to how 1 (or -1) is a limit point. Of course both 1 and (-1) are _limits_ of the subsequences of even and odd terms respectively, but they don't seem to be _limit points_.

Comment: You say (my emphasis) "[b]ut isn't a limit point (say, p) of a **set** [...]" That's true for a set, but not relevant here, as the question concerns limit points of a *sequence.* The limit points of a sequence are not the same as a the limit points of the set of values it attains. The limit points of a sequence are, as said in the answer, the limits of its convergent subsequences. It is not too far off though. One can show  that the limit points of the sequence are the limits points of the underlying set *and* the values attained infinitely often by the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the sequence $\{1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,...\}$ has two limit points: $-1$ and $1$. Take, for instance, the odd-indexed terms of the sequence and even-indexed terms of the sequence.

This is the Bolzano-Weierstrauss theorem: any bounded sequence has a convergent **sub**sequence.

Comment: But a sequence can not have two limits, right? Probably the two limits are for each of the two underlying sub-sequences as you pointed out correctly. That is Bolzano-Weierstrauss theorem. I now understand the difference between 'limit' and 'limit points'.

Comment: As @quid says, there is a distinction between a sequence "having a limit" and the image of a sequence "having limit points." The point $-1$ is a limit point because every $\epsilon$-ball around $-1$ contains a point of the sequence (namely $-1$ itself) and similarly for 1.

Answer (score 1):

As answered already, the theorem is about sub-sequential limit. You should read about Cantor's lemma (which basically says that a series of closed intervals has a unique element c which is in all the intervals if and only if the limit of the interval, defined as |a-b| converges to 0), then take a look at the Bolzano - Weierstrass theorem.